# Generate C# from razor (blazor)

Tags: razor, blazor, code-generation

Im trying to generate the g.cs from code using package

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="6.0.5" />
```

Sample code to compile razor into cs:

```
        var engine = RazorProjectEngine.Create(RazorConfiguration.Default, RazorProjectFileSystem.Create(pathWhereCsProjLives));
        var file = engine.FileSystem.GetItem("/pages/Counter2.razor");
        var document = engine.Process(file).GetCSharpDocument();
        var generatedCode = document.GeneratedCode;
```

It does not work properly. For intance a button will be generated like this:

```
__builder.AddMarkupContent(5, "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" @onclick=\"IncrementCount\">Click me</button>");
```

Should be something like:

```
        __builder.OpenElement(5, "button");
        __builder.AddAttribute(6, "class", "btn btn-primary");
        __builder.AddAttribute(7, "onclick", Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback.Factory.Create<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs>(this, IncrementCount
        ));
        __builder.AddContent(8, "Click me");
        __builder.CloseElement();
    }
```

Comment: Despite their similar names, Blazor and Razor are very different technologies.  Razor as used here (and as used by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language`) is about server-side generation of HTML content that is then sent to the client.  Blazor is generally about generating HTML in the client (most clearly and obviously manifested in the web assembly variant).  Blazor functionality can mostly be found in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` namespace.  Given all that, you should explain what you are actually trying to accomplish since your current approach isn't going to work.

Comment: Working on a designer where users can write blazor components with a live-preview (hot-reload has way to many limitations for now).
Basicly I want to create the g.cs which Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators does.
file.razor -> file.g.cs. Or even better if there is a method that can take razor component and create type at runtime.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I'm trying to accomplish the same

Comment: No! Current solution is to call dotnet build for full project, and I hate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have try another syntax

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=@OnClickFunc> ClickMe </button>
```

it generated

```
        __builder.CloseElement();
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(5, "\n");
        __builder.OpenElement(6, "button");
        __builder.AddAttribute(7, "class", "btn btn-primary");
        __builder.AddAttribute(8, "onclick", OnClickFunc);
        __builder.AddContent(9, " ClickMe ");
        __builder.CloseElement();
    }

    private void OnClickFunc() {
        Console.WriteLine("OnClick");
    }
```

and it works well here.

using
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language" Version="6.0.13" />`